# How to break a loop if "break" is inside fork-join?

Tags: system-verilog

I need to break a `repeat` loop, whose `break` decision is made inside a fork-join block, but my simulator doesn't compile the code that has the following structure.

```
repeat (10) begin
    fork
        begin
            // do something
        end
        begin
            #(100ms);
            break; // compile error
        end
    join_any
    disable fork;
end
```

I also tried the `disable` command. I was able to compile, but it didn't break the loop.

```
repeat (10)
begin : repeat10_loop
    fork
        begin
            // do something
        end
        begin
            #(100ms);
            disable repeat10_loop; // try
        end
    join_any
    disable fork;
end : repeat10_loop
```

Is there a way to use `break` or `disable` inside fork-join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `break` and `continue` statements must be within the same process as the loop statement. The problem with your disable is you incorrectly labeled your loop. Try:

```
repeat10_loop: repeat (10)
   begin
```